# Unable to creating disk with python code when disk type is specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am creating disk using python3. While try to create a disk, I am using the below config for body. I am able to create a disk if I am not using "type": "pd-standard" or "type": "pd-ssd":

```
config = {
    "name": "mytestdisk",
    "description": "this disk is created using python code",
    "sizeGb": '1',
    "type": "pd-standard",
    "zone": zone
}
```

But when using "type": "pd-standard" or "type": "pd-ssd" I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/cretedisk.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(create_disk(compute, project, zone))
  File "C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/cretedisk.py", line 24, in create_disk
    return compute.disks().insert(
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/superman/zones/us-central1-a/disks?alt=json returned "Invalid value for field 'resource.type': 'pd-standard'. The URL is malformed.">
```

The url should be

```
'type': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/superman/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard',
'type': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/superman/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-ssd'
```

I am not sure why it is trying the incorrect url:

```
https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/superman/zones/us-central1-a/disks
```

To me it looks like there is a bug in the library. Has anyone tried and faced such issue or have a solution to this error?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your the `create_disk` function in your `cretedisk.py` file?

Comment: @Dustin: I am sorry but I am not able to understand your above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks, the `type` field says:

> URL of the disk type resource describing which disk type to use to create the disk. Provide this when creating the disk. For example: `projects/<project>/zones/<zone>/diskTypes/pd-standard`

I think you want the full URL for `type` instead of just `pd-standard`, so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/superman/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-standard
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time. You are right. Even I was also looking the same page but somehow missed the above pasted url statement. May be because I was not expecting that I have to repeat the project name and zone when I am already passing these details in project and zone parameter while calling compute.disks().insert.

I think google should correct this as there is no significance of passing project and zone when you have to repeat the same in type parameter.